# How to pass key/values to multi-line C3.JS Chart with automated timeseries x-axis?

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I have timeseries data. On the server, I generate an x array, and three arrays of values (all of equal length).

However, the x array doesn't always go month to month. Sometimes it skips a couple of months. When this happens, the x-axis is very spaced out. Is there a good way to generate range of labels on the x-axis, and pass key values for different lines so that the entire line's values are still represented in the chart.

Currently I have:

```
  var chart = c3.generate({
       bindto: "#" + this.chart.chartId,
       data: {
          x: 'x',
          columns: [
              ["x", "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01, "2015-06-01", "2016-01-01"],
              ["data1", 5, 8, 2, 9]
              ["data2", 3, 10, 2, 1]
              ["data3", 1, 8, 4, 9]
       },
       subchart: {
          show: true
       },
       axis: {
       x: {
          type: 'timeseries',
          extent: ['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01'],
             tick: {
             format: '%Y-%m-%d'
          }
      }
  }
```

});
Any advice is appreciated to solve this spaced out issue for timeseries.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking about addressing x axes with c3, but your tags suggest that you are open to a solution with D3. Looking at your JSON string and seeing the node `x.extent` I would suggest trying something like this:

```
// setup x axes
var minDate = yourJSON.x.extent[0], maxDate = yourJSON.x.extent[1],
xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([maxDate,maxDate]).range([0, width]),
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));

var svg = d3.select("#chart-content").append("svg")...etc;

        // x-axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("x", width)
            .attr("y", -6)
            .style("text-anchor", "end");
```

Since you are specifying a range, D3 will expose time in between those dates.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll give it a shot.